# What would cause WPF DragDelta values to become suddenly cumulative with each call?

Tags: wpf

I have UserControl wrapping a zoomable canvas with shapes that the user can drag.

Recently I tried to make changes to follow the advice I got in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374444/are-wpf-inherited-attached-dependency-properties-expensive?noredirect=1#comment91730994_52374444);  Instead applying one transform to the the whole canvas with shapes, I tried to apply it individually to each shape's Geometry.  The idea was to eliminate zooming effects on font sizes and line thicknesses.

Unfortunately, although I have most of it working (shapes show up where they should) I seem to have broken the dragging of individual shapes across the canvas.  I cannot explain why.

The symptom is that the DragDelta event handler is reporting ***cumulative*** values for each HorizontalChange and VerticalChange.  So my shapes now zoom off the edge of the screen with even small movements.  They use to not be that way.

(Setting the "Handled" boolean on the event args has no effect)

I've posted some code below.  While I am grateful to anyone who bothers to read through it, I'm actually more interested in the general concept of how someone can make DragDelta report cumulative values at all.  The documentation states that they're only supposed to be the values since the last call to DragDelta.

I cannot be the first person to make this mistake.  Is this a common problem with a common cause?

Anyway if you are still reading, here's the detail.  The shapes are represented by an interface, IShape.

```
public interface IShape
{
    Geometry RelativeGeometry { get; }  // Geometry relative to shape origin
    Geometry AbsoluteGeometry { get; }  // Geometry relative to canvas origin
}
```

The IShape objects are drawn in an ItemsControl on a Canvas inside my UserControl

```
<Canvas x:Name="Scene">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ShapesLayer" ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}"
                  ItemTemplate={StaticResource ShapeTemplate}"/>
</Canvas>
```

This is the ItemTemplate the items control uses to draw an IShape

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ShapeTemplate" DataType="{x:Type gci:IShape}">
    <Canvas>
        <!-- Visible shape (not selectable) -->

        <Path Data="{Binding AbsoluteGeometry, {StaticResource TransformGeometry}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource Trans}}"
              IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

        <!-- Invisible but selectable thumb control for dragging shape -->

        <Thumb">
            <Thumb.Style>
                <EventSetter Event="DragDelta"             Handler="Shape_DragDelta"/>
            </Thumb.Style>
            <Thumb.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Path Fill="Transparent" Stroke="Transparent">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="{Binding AbsoluteGeometry.Bounds}"
                                               Transform="{StaticResource Trans}"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Thumb.Template>
        </Thumb>
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is the DragDelta handler for the shape thumb control in code-behind

```
private void Shape_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is FrameworkElement fe) || !(fe.DataContext is IShape shape))
        return;

    // Move each selected shape by the delta.

    var v = new Vector {X = e.HorizontalChange, Y = e.VerticalChange};
    foreach (var s in Shapes.Where(shp => shp.IsSelected))
    {
        if (s.Offset(v) && !(_movedShapes.Contains(s)))
            _movedShapes.Add(s);

    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Finally, this is the transform, declared in my control's resources and used by all shapes.  It builds off of custom Scale and OffsetX/OffsetY dependency properties in the control.  My control sets those values in code-behind with mouse/touch handlers.  They are propagated to this resource and thus to the shapes.

```
<TransformGroup x:Key="Trans">

    <!-- "Root" is the name of the control.  It exposes custom dependency
    properties "ZoomScale, "OffsetX" and "OffsetY" which apply to the entire
    control and therefore are not changed when a shape is dragged  -->

    <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" 
                    ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ZoomScale}" 
                    ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ZoomScale}"
    />
    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=OffsetX}" 
                        Y="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=OffsetY}"/>
</TransformGroup>

<!-- Value Converter that applies a transform to a Geometry  -->

<gcc:TransformGeometryConverter x:Key="TransformGeometry"/>
```

Comment: The problem is that the Thumb doesn't move. A DragDelta's HorizontalChange and VerticalChange are relative to the thumb's last position in its parent element. You would need to set and update the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties of the Thumb.

Comment: Or perhaps apply an appropriate Transform to its LayoutTransform.

Comment: Ah, of course (smacks self on head).   Thank you.  Gods, I'm blind.  I cannot believe I didn't grasp that.  The previous approach of my code did indeed do that (i.e. used Canvas.Left/Canvas.Top for positioning).  But I was so concerned here with properly updating the shape's geometry, I forgot all about updating the Thumb itself.   At this point, all this updating of individual geometries seems so non-intuitive that it might be better for me to go back to just zooming the whole canvas and manually scaling font sizes/line-thicknesses to compensate.

Comment: To me it seems questionable whether a Thumb is the right element at all to react on mouse input on your shapes. At least you want to draw those shapes by geometries that all have the same coordinate origin. There is hence no actual positioning done by layout with which a Thumb could operate. I think it would be more suitable that the ItemsControl or its ItemsPanel processes mouse input and moves the shape items appropriately.

Comment: I liked the simplicity of Thumb and its built-in events for dragging.  It seemed custom made for it.  This was the first time it became a complication.   The only alternative I could see was manually writing the MouseDown/MouseMove/MouseUp handlers myself, remembering last positions, all that stuff Thumb does.    I started this change on code that worked perfectly because it seemed like it would result in code that would be less verbose, easier-to-understand, and more maintainable.  For future developers.  Now I'm not sure that would be the result

Comment: You can just divide the delta by the zoom. e.VerticalChange / zoom